# Using @Mock and @InjectMocks

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm currently studying the Mockito framework and I've created several test cases using Mockito.
But then I read that instead of invoking mock(*SomeClass*.class) I can use the `@Mock` and the `@InjectMocks` - The only thing I need to do is to annotate my test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or use the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in the `@Before` method.

But it doesn't work - It seems that the `@Mock` won't work!
Here is my 2 codes revisions - one using the annotations and one without.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ReportServiceImplTestMockito {

    private TaskService       mockTaskService; // This is the Mock object
    private ReportServiceImpl service;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        service         = new ReportServiceImpl();
        mockTaskService = mock(TaskServiceImpl.class);
        service.setTaskServiceImpl(mockTaskService);
    }
/// ...

 Some tests
}
```

As I said - this work great.
But the following wont:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ReportServiceImplTestMockito {

     @Mock 
     private TaskService      mockTaskService;

     @InjectMocks 
     private ReportServiceImpl service;

         // Some tests
}
```

And here is the `ReportServiceImpl` class:

```
@Service
public class ReportServiceImpl implements ReportService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskServiceImpl;

    public ReportServiceImpl(){}

    public ReportServiceImpl(TaskService taskService){
        this.taskServiceImpl = taskService;
    }

    public void setTaskServiceImpl(TaskService taskServiceImpl) {
        this.taskServiceImpl = taskServiceImpl;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks OK to me, at first glance.  What exactly is going wrong for you?

Comment: @Noam Are you sure you are using the correct imports ?

Comment: David - I'm getting a NullPointerException. And Brice, I believe I'm using the right imports - here they are 'import org.jmock.auto.Mock;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

O.K, I got my mistake!!!
I've used the `@InjectMocks` but initialized the same variable in the init() method...
So what happened was that mockito injected the mock objects to my variable - but seconds later I ran it over - initializing that very same variable!!!

Comment: Thank god for this question and self-realization answer. I was losing my hair over it.

Answer (score 12):

Your code works fine for me using Mockito 1.9.

Using an 1.8+ version of Mockito I get a very specific error message telling me exactly how to fix the problem. As php-coder suggests: For Mockito 1.8+ you need to initialize the field.

Did you see this or any other error message?

**Edit:**

The following code works for me. Small changes:

- Removed Spring annotations
- Removed Interface
- Added Getter
- Added empty `TaskService`
- Added test with `System.out.println`

Does it produce an error for you? :

Service:

```
public class ReportServiceImpl {

    private TaskService taskServiceImpl;


    public ReportServiceImpl() {

    }


    public ReportServiceImpl(TaskService taskService) {
        this.taskServiceImpl = taskService;
    }


    public void setTaskServiceImpl(TaskService taskServiceImpl) {
        this.taskServiceImpl = taskServiceImpl;
    }


    public TaskService getTaskServiceImpl() {
        return taskServiceImpl;
    }
}
```

Dependency:

```
public class TaskService {

}
```

Test, prints `mockTaskService`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ReportServiceImplTestMockito {

    @Mock
    private TaskService       mockTaskService;

    @InjectMocks
    private ReportServiceImpl service;


    @Test
    public void testMockInjected() {
        System.out.println(service.getTaskServiceImpl());
    }
}
```

Comment: As I say, the code works for me. Can you test the code I posted (small changes only)?

Comment: Hi Arend, sorry for the delay - but your code works for me as well, I've used a worng import for the @Mock annotation - import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations; instead of import org.mockito.Mock;

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but try to create new instance of `ReportServiceImpl` manually (as you did in working example):

```
 @InjectMocks 
 private ReportServiceImpl service = new ReportServiceImpl();
```

Comment: This is not anymore necessary since Mockito 1.9 at the exception of edge case.

Comment: If you are using 1.8, you need to instantiate it in the initializer or the constructor unless you are using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in which case, you need to instantiate it before that is called.

Comment: First, thanks for the replies. but useing MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) is not neccesary since I used @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class).